# Concourse build docker-image copying from git repo

Tags: docker, dockerfile, concourse, concourse-git-resource, concourse-pipeline

I am trying to use a Concourse pipeline to pull a git repo and then build/push a Docker image from the dockerfile in the git repo. The dockerfile has a COPY command in it to copy files from the repo into the image. Normally I'd mount a volume to be able to COPY those files in at build time, but not finding a way to do that in Concourse. Here's what I'm trying:

```
# pipeline.yml
resources:  
  - name: git-repo
    type: git
    source:
      uri: <the-git-url>
      branch: master
      private_key: ((source-git-ssh-key))
  - name: my-image
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: gcr.io/path_to_image
      username: _json_key
      password: ((gcp-credential))

jobs:
  ...
      - get: git-repo
        trigger: true
      - put: my-image
        params:
          build: git-repo/compose



# dockerfile located at git-repo/compose/Dockerfile
FROM ...
...
# git-repo/scripts/run-script.sh
COPY scripts/run-script.sh /
...
```

How can I make the file git-repo/scripts/run-script.sh available to be copied into my image at build time? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Concourse, but as a rule with Docker you can only `COPY` things into your image that are contained in your build context (that is, they are in the build directory or a subdirectory of the build directory).  From you configuration file...

```
      - put: my-image
        params:
          build: git-repo/compose
```

It looks like your build context is `git-repo/compose`. Since the script you want to include is *outside* of that directory (`git-repo/scripts/run-script.sh`), it's not going to be available during the build process.

The solution is to reorganize your `git-repo`.  For example, you could:

- Move the `scripts/` directory into your `compose/` directory.
- Move the `Dockerfile` out of `compose/` and into the main `git-repo` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I found there's a solution wihtout reorganizing the repo (which is outside my control). I'll post it shortly

Answer (score 0):

Found a way. The build context is assumed to be the base dir (e.g. `git-repo/compose` in the example). As a result, the files I wanted to copy in were outside the directory I had available. If your Dockerfile isn't in the root dir, you need to specify it in the `dockerfile` param if you still want access to the rest of the same/higher-level files. Working example:

```
  - put: my-image
    params:
      build: git-repo
      dockerfile: git-repo/compose/Dockerfile
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I suggested (making the main `git-repo` directory your build context). It's good that don't have to move the Dockerfile, but otherwise this is the same solution.